# Window form disable window tablet's automatical orientation programmatically

Tags: winforms

My desktop application does not support if the tablet's orientation change! Can i disable the screen orientation programmatically?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn629268%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: can i make this change by c#?

Comment: Of course, you can pinvoke the function.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10793108/how-to-get-the-screen-auto-rotates-status